# multiple partialViews, RadioButtonFor name conflict

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a project in which I render various models (list of models even) and some of these have radio buttons. Unfortunately, in my HTML output all radio buttons now have the same name (I can easily change their IDs, but name change fails), which means radio button selection jumps between groups. What options do I have? Ideally something which would still allow me to bind to my models fairly easily.

Thanks,
Leo

**One of PartialView:**

```
@model Forms.Models.RatioReq
@{ 
    this.ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
}

@foreach (var item in Model.options)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model=>model.ratioVal, item.value, new {id="id_" + Model.FieldID + "_" + item.value, Name="blahblahIdontgetapplied"}
    <label>@item.name</label>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of RadioButtonFor, can't you simply use RadioButton?

Here is what you next should do

```
 @Html.RadioButton("yourNameThatWillGetApplied", item.value, new {id="id_" + Model.FieldID + "_" + item.value})
```